# How to call multiple GET requests using a resource factory in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Here is my code for factory method using $resource

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services")
    .factory("lookupResource", ["$resource", "appsettings", lookupResource])
    function lookupResource($resource, appsettings) {
        return {
            lookupUserRoles: $resource(appsettings.serverpath + "api/UserRoles", null,
                {
                    'userRoles': { method: 'get' }
                }),
            lookupStaffTypes: $resource(appsettings.serverpath + "api/StaffTypes", null,
                {
                    'staffTypes': { method: 'get' }
            })
        }
    }

})();
```

I am trying to call the **lookupStaffTypes** using below code but it gives no data or error. What am I missing here?

```
   lookupResource.lookupStaffTypes.staffTypes( function (data) {
                var test = data;
            },
                function (response) {
                    vm.message = response.statusText + "\r\n"
                    if (response.data.exceptionMessage)
                    { vm.message += response.data.exceptionMessage }
                    //validation errors
                    if (response.data.error) {
                        vm.message += response.data.error;
                    }
                });
```

Where as I can call like this and it gives me data:

```
 var staffTypes = $http.get(appsettings.serverpath + "api/StaffTypes").then(function (dataResponse) {
            var qwe = dataResponse;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataResponse.data.length; i++) {
                $scope.staffTypeList.push(dataResponse.data[i]);
            }

        }, function (response) {
            vm.message = response.statusText + "\r\n"
            if (response.data.exceptionMessage)
            { vm.message += response.data.exceptionMessage }
            //validation errors
            if (response.data.error) {
                vm.message += response.data.error;
            }
        });
```

I am new to angular and any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(test)`? Also, have you injected `ngResource` in your module?

Comment: @vishtree- test is coming as undefined and I have injected ngResource to common.services module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend avoiding the [ngResource module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) and just using the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) directly. If a server implements a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), I recommend using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

That said, for ngResource:

If the server returns an array, it is important to define the action method with  `isArray: true`:

```
app.factory("lookupResource", ["$resource", "appsettings", lookupResource])
function lookupResource($resource, appsettings) {
    return {
        lookupStaffTypes: $resource(appsettings.serverpath + "api/StaffTypes", null,
            {
                'staffTypes': { method: 'get',
                                isArray: true }
        })
    }
}
```

Invoke it with:

```
$scope.staffTypeList = lookupResource.lookupStaffTypes.staffTypes();

//OR

$scope.staffTypeList = lookupResource.lookupStaffTypes.query();
```

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

If the service expects an object but receives an array, or vice versa, it will generate a [$resource:badcfg error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg). If the service returns a boolean or a string, the action method will quietly return nothing.

Use the `$promise` propery of the received object (or array) to chain sequential operations:

```
$scope.staffTypeList.$promise.then(function(staffTypeList) {
    console.log(staffTypeList);
    //Do more stuff
});
```

Comment: But I don't think he is expecting an array from API. When he fired get request with $http, he is getting an object, not array. @libin-m correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `dataResponse.data` is an array. But `dataResponse` is an object, which means response is an object. Thats my understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `dataResponse.data` is an array. Thus it is necessary to set `isArray: true`.

Comment: @georgeawg - This is what I was returning "return Ok(PreEmploymentEntity.luStaffTypes);" and I thought it's not an array but the code you gave here works. This is how I used it:    var y = lookupResource.lookupStaffTypes.staffTypes();
             y.$promise.then(function (todo) {
                // success
                alert(todo);

            }, function(errResponse) {
                // fail
            });

Comment: I am glad the answer helped you.